# Sending form data to E-mail using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

this is my first experience with PHP so sorry for the simple question.
I have a form in my website and I'm trying to send the user data to my E-mail (this means: when the user finish to fill the fields and click on "submit", I want to receive an E-mail with all the data he entered). After sending the data, I want that instead of the form field and submit button, a message "Thank you for contact us" will appear. So long I tried to do it this way:

My form:

```
    <form id="contactForm" method="post" action="contact.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name">

            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail Address">

            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">

            <input type="text" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Company">

        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Write Your Message Here..."></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="submitForm">
    <div id="formValidationAlerts">
</form>
```

My PHP code.

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="minorb@gmail.com";
    $subject="Message from Webtopia";
    $sender=$_POST["name"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["email"];
    $senderPhone=$_POST["phone"];
    $senderCompany=$_POST["company"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];

    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\nPhone: $senderPhone\nCompany: $senderCompany\n\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

$thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}

?>
```

How can I continue from here? So long, when I clicked on submit I just move to the contact.php page and see my PHP code at the browser as plain text.

Thanks

Comment: Have you configured php server?

Comment: Can you give us some more info about the serever you're using and your OS?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Max OS X and I run it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't in your code, but in the server set-up. The PHP code not being run means either HTTP server (Apache, nginx, etc.) or PHP server misconfiguration. Look for advices on running MAMP.